# Closure formula in letters [e.g "Look forward to hearing from you"]

Tags: english-to-german, letter

I would like to know some closure formula for both formal and informal letters. I'm a beginner, hence I know only the classical and easy

> Viele Grüße, bis bald!

for informal letters. I am looking for some other polite formula; indeed, how can one say "Look forward to hearing from you soon"? Is it something like

> Ich hoffe, bald von Dir zu hören.

What about formal letters? I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: for formal closure see: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/what-is-the-accurate-translation-of-best-regards-to-finish-a-letter - more generally see http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/245/unterschied-zwischen-schriftlichen-abschiedsformeln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the questions linked by Takkat, the best translation for `look forward to hearing from you {soon}` would be:

> In Erwartung einer {baldigen} Antwort

`Erwartung` can also bear an adjective e.g. `freudig`, `groß`. If it does, then `einer {baldigen} Antwort` can be left. But `In Erwartung` would be inappropriate.

Be aware, that this formula is highly uncommon and will most probably confuse the reader at least slightly.

Comment: So hat man vielleicht vor 100 Jahren geschlossen.

Comment: @userunknown Ja, deswegen ja auch der Endsatz.

Answer (score 2):

Im Geschäftsverkehr duzt Du natürlich nicht, sonst geht die Formulierung auch problemlos dort:

```
Ich hoffe bald von Ihnen zu hören.
```

Die steifen Formen der Kaiserzeit benutzen nur Leute, die nicht viel schreiben. Sich an den Formeln der Absender zu orientieren, die man gerne überliest, kann auch inspirieren.