# Sincere closing to condolence letter to grandmother-in-law

Tags: letter, valediction

I’m looking for a heartfelt way to close a condolence letter to my grandmother-in-law after the recent death of her husband.

The standard German closing *mit lieben Grüßen* seems too casual for this situation.

In English, I’d say something like *with all my heart* or *from the bottom of my heart* to emphasize my sincerity. It’s a bit kitschy, but I think it gets the feeling across.

Can I say *aus tiefstem Herzen* in German? Or is there a better way to express this?

The whole letter would be something like:

> Liebe Oma,
>
> … details …
>
> Mein herzliches Beileid. Meine Gedanken sind bei euch.
>
> Aus tiefstem Herzen,
>
> Cecilia

Comment: Edited for grammar (aus tiefste**m** Herzen). Also, consider using **E**uch (i.e., uppercase letter). Your version is not wrong, but the uppercase is still favored by the older generation.

Comment: Although that only applies if there is somebody living with your grandmother-in-law who could also be addressed with the *euch*. If she only lived with her husband (thus is living alone now), consider using *dir* or *Dir* instead.

Comment: @Jan My mother-in-law is also living there.

Comment: Then it’s better to use *euch/Euch*, true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not?

You are writing a personal, heartfelt letter, so feel free to use personal, heartfelt words.

If you were writing a formal letter sticking to formalized greeting would be advisable (find posts on this subject [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/what-is-the-accurate-translation-of-best-regards-to-finish-a-letter) and [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/245/unterschied-zwischen-schriftlichen-abschiedsformeln) (thanks, @chirlu)), for personal use, these rules are rather loose – especially in special circumstances. Writing the infamous *mit freundlichen Grüßen* would – to my ears – sound odd.

As it stands, I see nothing wrong with your suggestion.
Consider capitalizing *Euch*, though. It’s optional for *du/Du* and *euch/Euch* nowadays, but elder people will have learned that in letters capitalizing personal pronouns is mandatory.

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/245/unterschied-zwischen-schriftlichen-abschiedsformeln may be what you were thinking of.

Comment: @chirlu: found another one, but yours is even better, thanks! Will edit again...